# Why is updating one object in state updating both?

Tags: reactjs, state

This is driving me crazy - I have a form for users to update account information, and I want to show a "remember to save when finished" notice when a user updates any of the inputs. To do this, I store the "user" object in state, along with an "originalUser" object in state. But when I update the "user" object it also updates the "originalUser" object!

Simplified code:

I get the user details from the database, and set the state:

```
this.setState({loaded: true, user: data.user, originalUser: data.user});
```

Then the ONLY place I make any update to state is in this function:

```
onInputChange = (input, val) => {
   let user = this.state.user;
   user[input] = val;
   this.setState({user: user});
    console.log(this.state.user);
    console.log(this.state.originalUser);
}
```

But the console logs the update happening to BOTH. For example, if the input is "first" and the value is "John" originally, and I change it to "Johnny," both "user" and "originalUser" have "first" being "Johnny." Why is originalUser getting updated here?

Comment: Modifying one modifies both because they are _the same object_. I think you need to learn how JavaScript references/objects/etc. work a little more before proceeding on to React. Also, you shouldn't be mutating (modifying) objects that are stored in your state. `user[input] = val; // <-- this is bad`.

Comment: I created a new variable "user" that is a copy of what is stored in state, then I modify that, then I update state. What is the right way, then, to modify the state.user object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assignment operator doesn't create a copy of an object, it only assigns a reference to it.
The spread operator will help if your object is not deeply nested

```
this.setState({loaded: true, user: {...data.user}, originalUser: {...data.user}});
```

Also don't mutate state directly. Use this instead:

```
let user = {...this.state.user};
user[input] = val;
this.setState({user: user});
```

Comment: Thanks! Still a bit confused because I thought the spread operator was used when you had nested objects in state. In this case, both "user" and "originalUser" are at the top level, so I'm still confused about why updating state.user would update state.originalUser. Anyway, your suggestion did work though, just trying to get my head around it.

Comment: @seeker70 because state.user and state.originalUser point to the same object. So when you modify state.user, you also modify state.originalUser.

Comment: This still isn't a complete solution. The `onInputChange` is still mutating a state object instead of using `setState` to update it.

Comment: Updated answer.